# Rows With Blank Entries in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a 721 x 26 dataframe. Some rows have entries that are blank. It's not NULL
or NA but just empty like the following. How can I delete those rows that have these kind of entries?

```
1         Y    N        Y          N            86.8
2         N    N        Y          N            50.0
3                                               76.8
4         N    N        Y          N            46.6
5         Y    Y        Y          Y            30.0
```

Comment: Have you tried `== ""` for matching the blanks?

Comment: What does "blank" mean exactly? Please post some sample data, using `dput()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to this question depends on how paranoid you want to be about the sort of things that might be in 'blank'-appearing character strings. Here's a fairly careful approach that will match the zero-length blank string `""` as well as any string composed of one or more `[[:space:]]` characters (i.e. "tab, newline, vertical tab, form feed, carriage return, space and possibly other locale-dependent characters", according to the `?regex` help page).

```
## An example data.frame containing all sorts of 'blank' strings
df <- data.frame(A = c("a", "", "\n", " ", " \t\t", "b"),
                 B = c("b", "b", "\t", " ", "\t\t\t", "d"),
                 C = 1:6)

## Test each element to see if is either zero-length or contains just
## space characters
pat <- "^[[:space:]]*$"
subdf <- df[-which(names(df) %in% "C")] # removes columns not involved in the test
matches <- data.frame(lapply(subdf, function(x) grepl(pat, x))) 

## Subset df to remove rows fully composed of elements matching `pat` 
df[!apply(matches, 1, all),]
#   A B C
# 1 a b 1
# 2   b 2
# 6 b d 6

## OR, to remove rows with *any* blank entries
df[!apply(matches, 1, any),]
#   A B C
# 1 a b 1
# 6 b d 6
```

Comment: What is the 'grepl' function?

Comment: It's like `grep`, except it returns `TRUE` for all matches and `FALSE` for non-matches. Try this to see: `grepl("a", c("ab", "b", "c", "a"))`. See also `?grepl` for the official documentation.

Comment: But in the resulting dataset still has a row that has a space. ( 2 b 2).

Comment: If you want to remove rows like row 2 that have **any** blank entries you can use `df[!apply(matches, 1, any),]` instead of `df[!apply(matches, 1, all),]`.

Comment: @Josh Where did the -3 come from in "matches <- data.frame(lapply(df[-3], function(x) grepl(pat, x)))?"

Comment: It's kind of a loose end. After seeing that your example data included a column of numbers with no blanks, I added one to my example to show you how to test for all but that column (column "C", the 3rd column in my example data set). So `df[-3]` just removes that column to make a subset of the matrix that is tested for blank elements. I just edited the answer to make that bit of code a bit clearer/cleaner.

Comment: I got the error "Error in data.frame(A = 2:5, B = 3:5, check.names = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = TRUE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 4, 3" after the "matches<-" line.

Comment: Well, I'd agree with the computer that `2:5` and `3:5` don't have the same length, as columns in a data.frame must. This doesn't have anything to do with your original question, and is just general error debugging.

Comment: Then how did you get that output?

Comment: Cutting and pasting my entire code into an R session just works. Is it giving you an error? If you're trying to run it on your own data.frame, you're likely going to need to make minor adjustments. From your description, I've no idea what you are doing to get that  error.